# SonarQube recognize Lombok Val as Bug

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a java program with a line of code like this in the corresponding test file:

```java
val transformedValue = engine.eval(script, bindings);
assertEquals(true, transformedValue);
```

We are using the `Lombok::val` here but SonarQube Report says this is a bug.

```
Change the assertion arguments to not compare dissimilar types.
```

Is there a flag which could be used so that sonar get the right datatype?

Comment: Reference: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5845

Comment: Lombok transforms your code into `Object transformedValue = engine.eval(script, bindings);`. And SonarQube warns when "_comparing an object with an unrelated primitive (E.G. a string with an int)_". A possible fix on your side might be to change the assertion to `assertEquals(Boolean.TRUE, transformedValue);`

Answer (score 0):

I assume value of `transformedValue` is `"true"`, so I recommend changing:

```java
assertEquals(true, transformedValue);
```

to

```java
assertEquals(true, new Boolean(transformedValue.toString()));
```

for getting the same type.

---

**Edit**

You can also create custom function:

```java
public void myAssertEquals(boolean bool, Object obj) {
  assertEquals(bool, new Boolean(obj.toString()));
}
```

Usage:

```java
myAssertEquals(true, transformedValue);
```

Comment: of course this is possible but doing such changes in a lot of places in the code is not what we really want to do to be honest

Comment: @Kevin you can create custom void function for that for less changes.